# perf -- record cache misses at thread level granularity

Tags: multithreading, caching, operating-system, profiling, perf

I'm currently trying to retrieve stats such as cache-misses grouped by thread IDs (the application I am profiling is run by OMP threads). Passing a comma separated list to `perf stat` using the `--tid` flag does not provide stats grouped by thread ID. Is there a way to go about this?